# changing "enabled" value of a button during runtime in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, button, mxml

i want to make a button disabled if a datagrid is empty and it should be enabled when there is atleast 1 entry.the entries in the grid are made at runtime.I tried this
this is the button:

```
<mx:Button id="update" label="Update Contact" enabled="{isButtonEnabled()}"/>
```

and the function is defined as where dg_contact is the datagrid:

```
public function isButtonEnabled():Boolean
{
     if(dg_contact.selectedIndex==-1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `isButtonEnabled()` doesn't get called when `selectedIndex` changes. You can use `BindingUtils` to do that, but this can be done without `BindingUtils`

`DataGrid` can have items and yet have its `selectedIndex` equal to -1. If you're not bothered about if an item is selected or not, bind it to the length of `DataGrid`'s `dataProvider`

```
<mx:Button id="update" label="Update Contact" 
               enabled="{dg_contact.dataProvider.length != 0}"/>
```

If you want button to be enabled only when something is selected, bind it to `selectedIndex`

```
<mx:Button id="update" label="Update Contact" 
               enabled="{dg_contact.selectedIndex != -1}"/>
```